# Galaxy S6 Edge Android USB driver

Tags: windows-10, android, lenovo-laptop

I've tried for two days to find a solution for this problem, but my research hasn't been successful. I tried Intel Android drivers, uninstalled from SDK manager and reinstalled Google USB drivers, changed MTP to media option, used stay awake screen option, and tried to manually install drivers. The OEM drivers the Google page links to for Lenovo are broken (I own a Lenovo G50-70 with Windows 10 64-bit.). It's also in Chinese. Even when it is translated, there is no download. I changed the fast charge cable with a standard one and the connect/disconnect cycle stopped suddenly, but Android Studio still doesn't recognize my phone.

It's unexplainable to me how there is no fix for this issue. Since there are millions of apps on the Play Store, Google needs to fix a lot. Most information, even on their pages, is outdated and has spelling errors. I'm sick and tired of this. If someone has found a solution, then please help.

It shows two entries, one MTP S6 Edge phone and one Android unrecognized device:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Samsung Kies](http://www.samsung.com/uk/support/usefulsoftware/KIES/) is the software that Samsung makes in order to communicate and backup their devices to a PC. This would be the absolute safest option rather than downloading the drivers from an unknown source.

It also includes a driver package that will install the full set of drivers needed for Samsung phones.

You can get it from [this site](http://www.samsung.com/uk/support/usefulsoftware/KIES/).

Comment: well the site also showed kies download. i downloaded that too but nope. even kies doesnt recognize my phone. the driver was the only solution. also, kies says its named now easy switch or something and prompts an update to that software version. kies is out of date.